# CATransform3D UIImageView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming, catransform3d

I am attempting to apply a `m34` transformation using `CATransform3DRotate`. My current structure is that I have a `UIScrollView` which hosts a `UIImageView`. The image view must be able to be zoomed and rotated as usual. There is also a 3D mode, similar to the apple maps 3D mode, which I have been attempting to simulate using a `m34` transform.

Two problems, first, the zoom resets the transform.
Second, the transform zooms into the image.

What is the correct way of handling this?